# Improving the Performance of MSChart Toolip in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, performance, tooltip, mschart

We are using MSChart on an ASP.net 3.5 web application and noticing significant slowness from enabling tooltips. the performance of drawing a chart is increased by 1,000-2,000ms.

The chart output is PNG, and contains in total 108 data points.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ImageStorageMode=UseHttpHandler ?

Comment: no i did not. How would that help? It seemed like the cause was from the isimagemap feature

Comment: well it would stop using the harddrive to temporarily save the files before delivering them to the client.